# delphi compiling error "[DCC Error] ProjectName.dpr([number]): E1026 File not found: 'FileName.dn'

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-2009

What is dn file?

why is delphi loooking for a file that should not be there(well I didn't create one)?

and how could it be fixed (compile)?

The error was generated after adding into existing project, a new file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some ODD reason, the auto added macro was gibberish and looked like this:

```
{$R *.dn}
```

in the new file that was added.

and also in the dpr file there was a mess with macros.

Changing it back to default solved it.